# eclipse helios WindowBuilder cant installing(sorry for bad typing)

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, ide, windowbuilder

After following these Steps I am getting these errors:

### Help > Install New Software > add > (Type SWT in the search field or general Purpose Tools
I downloaded the WB zip file from eclipse's site because WB plugins did not appear when searching in the section.) but ı getting these errors:

```
 Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: WindowBuilder Core Documentation 1.12.0.202306071608 (org.eclipse.wb.doc.user.feature.feature.group 1.12.0.202306071608)
  Missing requirement: WindowBuilder Core 1.12.0.202306071608 (org.eclipse.wb.core 1.12.0.202306071608) requires 'bundle org.apache.commons.collections 3.2.2' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: WindowBuilder Core 1.12.0.202306071608 (org.eclipse.wb.core.feature.feature.group 1.12.0.202306071608)
    To: org.eclipse.wb.core [1.12.0.202306071608]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: WindowBuilder Core Documentation 1.12.0.202306071608 (org.eclipse.wb.doc.user.feature.feature.group 1.12.0.202306071608)
    To: org.eclipse.wb.core.feature.feature.group 1.9.0
```

I don't understand what does this error mean?

Comment: Eclipse Helios (3.6) is 13 years and 28 releases old, the current version of window builder is not going to work in such an ancient release. The apache.commons.collections plug-in that is missing is only in the most recent releases of Eclipse.